# Best way to say that some phrases/words are part of a song

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the best way to say (and why) that some phrases/words of the lyrics belong to the song? For example, the Linkin Park's song called "Breaking The Habit".

1. "Memories consume", "Like opening the wound" and "I'm picking me apart again" are parts of the song "Breaking The Habit" lyrics.
2. "Memories consume", "Like opening the wound" and "I'm picking me apart again" are parts of the "Breaking The Habit" lyrics.
3. "Memories consume", "Like opening the wound" and "I'm picking me apart again" are parts of the song "Breaking The Habit".
4. "Memories consume", "Like opening the wound" and "I'm picking me apart again" are an excerpt from the song "Breaking The Habit" lyrics.
5. "Memories consume", "Like opening the wound" and "I'm picking me apart again" are an excerpt from the "Breaking The Habit" lyrics.
6. "Memories consume", "Like opening the wound" and "I'm picking me apart again" are an excerpt from the song "Breaking The Habit".

Or otherwise?

My question is which of these six phrases (or some other) is correct and would be the most natural to be used: with "song", "lyrics" or both words; 
should I use "an excerpt", "parts" or other (like phrases, words)?

Answer (score 1):

You can say it many different ways in English, but I personally would go for this one:

> "You are..." are words from a song called "I'm".

or this one:

> "You are..." are words from the song "I'm".

The reason I'd use these particular versions is because that's the most natural way to express the idea that the words you're talking about in fact come from a song.